# 2011 Qianjiang Motorcycles 50cc engine assembly step by step?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, vacuum, diagram

***Qianjiang*** is the MFG
**2011***50cc moped*
**What is the quickest way to start this engine? What needs to be installed?**
I have all parts plus extras, except for air box. I'm sure the vacuum hoses is going to be my battle because this one was already taken off. It had aftermarket air filter,also I did do a valve adjustment on it already, and noticed they had already plugged the exhaust hole or whatever.

Comment: what is your specific engineering question? ... the questions you asked require a manual to be written